# React Native mapStateToProps not setting state +Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

This could be an issue with my understanding of how RN runs, but I have a working WebApp and am using the same `Redux` setup. When I run a `dispatch` action I do see the proper information in the console as the call is successful, however I am not seeing the proper interaction within the app.

I'm providing a [Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/dnorthrupva/7548ef09ca22abf3cf8e933993dfab24) to avoid leaving out important pieces of the components, but these are the 3 components involves presently.

In my Web App, I initiate the store in index.js -

- In my Web App, I initiate the store in index.js
- I then run my dispatch to get characters in App.js
- I then mapStateToProps a couple laters down in may Layout component to have free access to it, via props.

I tried to implement this within RN a few ways:

- `App.js` initiated the store - Works.
- `HomeScreen.js` initiated the dispatch - Made the call but didn't update the state
- `Character.js` `mappedStateToProps` - Didn't work as there was no state.

None of this seemed to make a difference; I don't know if I'm abusing `App.js` in RN for expecting it to do too much lifting compared to `App.js` of ReactJS.

Welcome any input.

Comment: You need to post your code

Comment: @PritishVaidya That would help; Done.

Comment: Since you've not bound `mapStateToProps`  `export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen);`, therefore it wont work

Answer (score 0):

In HomeScreen Container you need to use **bindActionCreators** in  mapDispatchToProps method.